# print date format in Velocity Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

I'm trying to create registration form using Spring MVC and Velocity as view. in the view there are inputs:
username
email
password
confirmpassword
birthday -> format MM/dd/yyyy

when user submit the form, my controller validate the form input/command. if there some error, it will show back to the view and print the birth day in correct format.

but the date printed as not formated date. I try use $dateTool.format('MM/dd/yyyy', $registration.BirthDay) but the birthday value still not formated.

any helps needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just incase you are missing the link to make it work -
http://javacompleteexamples.blogspot.in/2009/07/velocity-example-with-for-loop-and-date.html
Note the important line - ctx.put("date", new DateTool());
replace date with dateTool or anything that you want to use in vm for formatting utility.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but since I bumped on it on Google, posting it in case someone else needs it:

try: $date.format('MM/dd/yyyy',$registration.BirthDay)